# using bibunits with eclipse

Tags: subdividing, bibunits

I am trying to create a publications list (sorted by patents, journal papers, & book chapters) for my CV and seems that bibunits is useful for this. However, I can't get it work. Below is the latex code I am using in eclipse editor & viewing the pdf file. Help me please with simple explanation (I am new to LaTeX & don't know much about computer languages).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}
\begin{bibunit}[plain]
    some text \cite{p1} more text more citations !
    \putbib[texlit]
\end{bibunit}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about eclipse, but `bibunut` requires to call several times `bibtex` one for each (bib)unit, i.e., `bibtex buX`, where `X` is a number corresponding to a bibunit. After that one can have a final call to LaTeX.

You can open the terminal (prompt, command line) and then run

```
pdflatex file
bibtex bu1
...
bibtex buN
pdflatex file
```

Where `file` is the name of your LaTeX file.

Comment: Thanks Guido. It's working now. In TeXworks, I first ran file.tex with "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX". Second, I ran the bu1,aux file with BibTeX. Then I ran the file.tex with "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX". It's time consuming to do it manually. Is there a way to automate this task in TeXworks?

Comment: If you don't have an index you do not have to run makeindex. Also after you run bibtex on the various bibunits, you do not have to run bibtex again.  Definitely you can create a script to automate the workflow: a possibility would be to use [arara](http://cereda.github.com/arara/).